The Green's function for the four-dimensional solution of the Proca equation is what?
From the Proca equation:
\begin{equation}
\color{red}{\partial_\mu}\color{blue}{\partial^\mu}A^\nu-m^2A^\nu=-4\pi J^\nu\\
\end{equation}
For the metric signature (-+++) and considering the steady-state solution with only three spatial variables, we have:
\begin{equation}
G=\frac{e^{-mR}}{R}\\
\end{equation}
However, when considering time and solving for the Green's function, we encounter a problem:
\begin{equation}
G=\text{Solve}[\color{red}{\partial_\mu}\color{blue}{\partial^\mu}G-m^2G=-4\pi \delta(x^\alpha-x'^\alpha)] \\ \Rightarrow  G=\int \frac{1}{4\pi^3}\frac{e^{ik_\mu(x^\mu-x'^{\mu})}}{k^\nu k_\nu+m^2}\text{d}^4k\\
\end{equation}
Assuming exponential decay for $k$, we get a non-integrable integral:
\begin{equation}
G=\frac{1}{2\pi R}\int e^{i(\sqrt{\omega^2-m^2}R-\omega\Delta t)}-e^{-i(\sqrt{\omega^2-m^2}R+\omega\Delta t)}\text{d}\omega\\
\end{equation}
How should I proceed from here?
